# Angular Simple filter on ng-Repeat (>5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a simple Angular form, where I'd like to filter the ng-repeat so that only values>5 are shown.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:value:>5??????/p>
    <p><input type=text ng-model="item.value"></p>
 </div>
</body>
```

I can't determine the syntax for this. I am assuming it's a built in filter.

Reference:

```
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.items = [ { value: 1 }, { value: 2 }, { value: 5}, { value: 7 } ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no filter built in for this, nor is there any syntax you can pass to the default filter.

You can either:

### 1. Pass a function to the default filter.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filterFn">
```

JS:

```
$scope.filterFn = function(item) {
  return item.value > 5;
};
```

### 2. Register your own filter

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | greaterThan:5">
```

JS:

```
app.filter('greaterThan', function() {
  return function(items, value) {

    var filtered = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (items[i].value > value) filtered.push(items[i]);
    }

    return filtered;
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you wrote some more text in it to explain what you're actually doing; it's a bit bare right now…

Comment: Use the first solution in the second one would be even better :) !